# Blazor IBrowserFile OpenReadStream() blocks UI thread

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, memorystream

I am trying to create a functionality to enable users to upload large files (upto 5GB).

Technically, unrelated to this issue but I am uploading them to s3 via multipart upload [I've tried both low level API and high level API but same issue].

My assumption is that OpenReadStream() is blocking the UI thread which is not allowing the Invoke(StateHasChanged) to update the state and hence the progress bar state. The progress bar updates to 100 after the entire upload is complete.

Tried to keep the reading logic in a separate task but no help

I've tried to create a fiddle after removing s3 logic and other unnecessary stuff for issue replication

Replication on Playground (doesn't contain the s3 logic -> Each chunk created is to be uploaded to s3 but after each iteration the progress isn't updated on the UI): https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/ceEPmiFO42DzRtyS17

Comment: You are using `StateHasChanged()` too frequently. What version of .Net are you using and what is the packet size and filesize where you first start to notice the runtime issues? You should decouple the processing from the UI update and might even consider a separate timer to update the UI. Overall I would simplify that code a lot. 2 nested try catch that do nothing is another code smell...

Comment: There is enough happening to keep the main thread occupied, but that is not the same as blocked. Insert `await Task.Delay(1)` after (some) StatehasChanged calls.

Comment: Server or WASM?  Net8 or lower? "My assumption is that some process is blocking the UI thread" is almost certainly correct.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Thanks for your inputs. 
I am using .NET 6. 
The extra StateHasChanged() calls are just me hoping a trial and error actually updates the UI state. 
Can't really completely decouple both processes as I get my file upload percentage from the number of byte chunks already read. 
I am wondering if there's a way to run the processing on a separate thread .
Extra Try catch as well just a part of debugging on the fiddle.

Comment: @ℍℍ Alright, let me try that.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Blazor Server on .NET 6

Comment: "CODE WORKS FINE ON MY LOCAL, ONLY FAILS TO UPDATE UI STATE WHEN DEPLOYED" suggests that the deployment environment restricts you to a single thread.  I'll be interested to see if @HH's `Task.Delay(1)` works.

Comment: You could set `ConfigureAwait` on some of the awaits to `false` and add some logging in the continuations to log which ThreadID the continuations are running on.

Comment: In the future, post (at least the relevant parts of) your code here, in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps anyone else, I found it the hard way, for the fact that the UI state doesn't update, @HH's answer kinda helps on WebAssembly as it did on https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/cIYPmZOM55C9v6M338 (you can check the logs)
BUT
It doesn't solve the issue on Blazor Server because as soon as you open a stream from a file your data starts flowing from client to the server and if the file is large enough it kinda hangs everything as well as rules out the benefit of uploading to s3 in multipart directly from client as you get an additional overhead of sending the file from client to server first and there the processing happens.

SOLUTION :
I would be investigating on a Javascript based solution with getting the secrets from AWS Secrets Manager for security on client side and advanced authentication mechanisms like S3AuthSigner.
Might as well use a npm package in Blazor with some external utility.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).